# SELECT COUNT across one-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, relational-database

For two tables

**player**

and

**team**

With a 1-∞ relationship (player to team): how would you count how many players belong to each team?

Failed attempt:

```
SELECT team.teamid, (SELECT COUNT(player.team) FROM player)
FROM team
LEFT JOIN player ON player.team = team.teamid
```

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it

Comment: Oh sure. Its MySQL: assumed the SQL was so generic in this case that it wouldn't make a difference

Comment: It might be straightforward sql, but you should always specify the rdbms you are using. :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT t.teamid, COUNT(p.team) player_count
FROM team t LEFT JOIN
     player p ON p.team = t.teamid
GROUP BY t.teamid
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52132/1)**

*It will give correct result event if some teams don't have players assigned. See sqlfiddle for that (team 3 doesn't have players).*

Comment: Can you achive same result using WHERE not JOINs?

Comment: @f1ames What is the reason for that?

Comment: Curiosity, and I prefer using WHEREs over JOINs. Plus I have somehow complex query joining 3 tables and it's easier to modify it than creating whole new query with joins:)

Answer (score 3):

It works for me

```
SELECT *, (select count(*) from receipt_note_stock b where 
b.receipt_note_id = a.id) from receipt_notes a
```