# MySQL relational table record count

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables: `clients` and `subcontractors`. Clients has many subcontractors. Subcontractors can have many clients.

My schema goes something like this:

```
clients
->id
->name
->status

subcontractors
->id
->client_id
->name
```

My question is how do I count clients with 1 to 2 subcontractors in them?

Thanks. I tried checking this one:

[SELECT COUNT across one-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506512/select-count-across-one-to-many-relationship)

But it seems that this is the reverse of what I am trying to count

Comment: `Clients has many subcontractors. Subcontractors can have many clients.` Why you are using **one to many** relation instead of **many to many** ?

Comment: @Imran How am I using one to many? Can you elaborate please? Thank you.

Comment: @ackhammer013 check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select count(*) count from (
  select c.id from clients c
  inner join subcontractors sc on sc.client_id=c.id
  group by c.id
  having count(*) in (1, 2)
) sub;
```

Answer (score 0):

> You should use **many to many** relation

I've answered because you want to know from me why you should use **many to many** relation instead of **one to many**. Because you said

> Clients has many subcontractors. Subcontractors can have many clients.

So your both tables should independent and for interaction you can use a map table this called `many to many` relation. Otherwise you query will more complicated and you need more nested subqueries for simple reason.

I've modified your structure

```
clients
-> id
-> name
-> status

subcontractors
-> id
-> name

client_subcontractors (this is your many to many relation)
-> id
-> client_id
-> subcontractor_id
```

#### And try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(`client_id`) AS total_client 
FROM `client_subcontractors` 
WHERE `subcontractor_id` IN (1, 2) 
GROUP BY `client_id` 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/572aa5/4)